# Help with Collocation #2: "time for caution" vs. "caution time"

Tags: collocations

This is to break my original question into three parts.

I really need your help with this. I get extremely frustrated when I don’t know how to know the right use of these cases. Please extend your help by providing me any websites or tips to fully understand and explore this.

- **This is a time for caution**

Why can’t you form a collocation here and say “**This is a caution time**”?

Please help me as much as you can with sources/websites/ tips/ anything that might help me know how to know the difference and use the right form.

Comment: You certainly **can** say "This is a caution time". We just don't. We use "a time for" or "a time to" when we urge people to take a specific action or adopt a specific attitude in a particular situation. *Play time*, *work time*, *Christmas time* are times set aside for different activities. That's the way we use *time*, and I'm afraid you just have to learn these uses one by one: there's no "rule", or even a useful "rule of thumb".

Comment: Okay. Do you know of a website that shows all of these uses one by one?

Comment: You need to edit your question to add *is* to your examples.

Comment: I'm afraid not. It would be huge: several times the size of a reasonably comprehensive dictionary. You could get a rough idea by Googling, and seeing how many actual hits you get (NOT that meaningless number Google posts at the top) and who wrote them.

Comment: So I should search for "common noun phrases"? Or "Noun collocations"? Or type each word I want to use and find its collocations?

Answer (score 1):

The first phrase is OK after adding a verb (is).

In your second phrase:

> This *is* a **caution** time.

Normally you need an adjective to modify the noun "time".

So this one should read:

> This *is* a **cautious** time.

If you intended *caution time* to be a noun phrase (for example if there was a particular time of day that was "caution time", then you could write:

> This *is* **caution time**.

Comment: Then why do we say " play time, work time, Chrismas time" ? There is no adjective before the noun.

Comment: Please check my edit; these would be like "caution time".

Comment: So if it is meant to be a noun phrase, we remove the comma? Can please tell me why?  I know that "Caution time" is countable. You can say there are caution times. Right?

Comment: Which comma do you mean?

Comment: This is (a) caution time.

Comment: That is *in parenthesis*. Whether you add an article or not depends on the actual meaning of "caution time". "This is" is not helpful, since I don't know what "this" refers to.